# Read JSON data in Python Socket Listener

Tags: python, json, http-post, python-sockets

So I am new to python and coding a simple script for my Raspberry Pi that listens for data on a socket listener. So far the following code works if I create a TCP client in C# and send data:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    data = conn.recv(1024)
    reply = 'OK...' + data
    if not data: 
        break
    option = int(data)

    conn.sendall(reply)

    doPiStuff(option)    

conn.close()
s.close()
```

However, using Fiddler, I created a HTTP Post and send some simple JSON data but the the data arrives null. Simple JSON data like:

```
{ "action":1 }
```

Forgive my lack of python experience, but what is the protocol for receiving data in a python socket listener, is it raw bytes or what?

Comment: This code would throw an error because `print data` is used before `data` is defined. But is that the line you're referring to as printing nothing?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my code, the code works with C# client sending data to this socket listener

Comment: @MarnusSteyn. what does `data` print ?

Comment: `{ action:1 }` is not a valid json format, it should be `{"action": 1}`

Comment: Tried that, didn;t work. Should there be something about how you package it? in the receive function, there is a byte size specified, what's that about